# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msgraph.generated.users'

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to run a Python application that uses msgraph-sdk. This error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msgraph.generated.users'` is happening in this method

```
async def get_user_groups(self, token: str) -> List[str]:
    credentials = OnBehalfOfCredential(tenant_id=TENANT_ID,
                                      client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                                      client_secret=self.aws_secret_manager_service.get_secret(),
                                      user_assertion=token)
    scopes = ['User.Read']
    graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credentials, scopes)
    result = await graph_client.me.member_of.get()

    groups = [group.id for group in result.value]
    return groups
```

Specifically in the line `result = await graph_client.me.member_of.get()`.

I checked the package and indeed there is no users module in it. There is a folder called "generated" with a lot of modules, but none of them is "users". The package version is `msgraph-sdk==1.1.0`. It looks like a bug in the package, but I've searched the whole internet and seems that nobody experienced this error before.

Here the full stack trace

```
  File "C:\Users\hesd\Documents\projects\backend\app\services\user.py", line 77, in get_user_groups
    user_azure_groups = await self.azure_ad_service.get_user_groups(token.get('jwt_token'))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hesd\Documents\projects\backend\app\services\azure_ad.py", line 20, in get_user_groups
    result = await graph_client.me.member_of.get()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\hesd\Documents\projects\backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\msgraph\graph_service_client.py", line 57, in me
    from .generated.users.item.user_item_request_builder import UserItemRequestBuilder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msgraph.generated.users'
```

Comment: did you install azure-identity in your python environment?

Comment: Hi, first, ensure that you have the correct version installed, and then try to update it
pip show msgraph-sdk
pip install --upgrade msgraph-sdk

Comment: Hi, I've got
azure-identity==1.15.0
msgraph-core==1.0.0
msgraph-sdk==1.1.0

Comment: I just checked again, I was using the wrong virtual env. I had only msgraph-core installed, it worked when I installed msgraph-sdk on the right environment, thanks